# ajax timeout problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i have long process in ajax that make problem
i added `asyncpostbacktimeout=600` to the script manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeOut="600" runat="server" ID="SmPage" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

in the local host its working great,
but when i tested it on the server it still have the some problem

any advise ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to increase `executionTimeout` in web.config otherwise the request itself is timing out.

Have a look at [executionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx) at msdn. It explains the difference between Debug=True/False and this is probably causing the difference between localhost and production.

> **executionTimeout**
>   Optional Int32 attribute.
>
> Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to
>   execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.
>
> This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False. If the debug attribute is True, to help avoiding
>   application shut-down while you are debugging, do not set this
>   time-out to a large value.
>
> The default is 110 seconds.

Add `executionTimeout` to `configuration/system.web/httpRuntime` in `Web.Config` and let me know if it works:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: HI jonas , i added the <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" /> but it still have the problem on the server

Comment: Ok, do you know if your request times out after 600 seconds or before? Ex [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is useful for this.